# Show Library view inside SPFx web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

Anyone knows of a way to show a filtered list of files in a SPO library with the 3 dots to get the version history and the other commands that exist in SharePoint itself?

Is there an option to do an iframe with calculated SharePoint URL?

Any PNP sample I missed?

Answer (score 0):

You could get file version history this way:

```
    let web = new Web(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl);
    web.lists.getByTitle("lib").items.getById(3).versions.get().then(r => {
    
          console.log(r)
        });
```

But it seems that it could not combine with filter.

Iframe Dialog components:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-iframe

https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/IFrameDialog/

Comment: Thank you Amos. I want t show a dynamic filter list of files. how to I construct the URL to show only the filtered rows without all the top and left.?

Comment: I figure out the filter https://MyTenant.sharepoint.com/teams/0100.009/DPCDocuments/Forms/Request.aspx?FilterField1={the Field}&FilterValue1={the Value} But I don't know how to eliminate all the top and left.

Comment: What do you mean all the top and left?

Comment: Without the header on top and quick link on the left. just the lines for each document in the filter.

Comment: I'd like to know how you made this hyperlink in a bit more detail. I'm trying to simply show a modal or filtered SPO list (in a webpart) from an email. Is it possible using SPFX?

Comment: You only need to fill in the url attribute of the iframedialog component and set the isopen attribute to true to display it.